# My valid SendGrid API key not working in via NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, sendgrid

I'm attempting you Send Grid's NodeJS code in a CSHTML web page to use their mail send service. For some reason the setApiKey command is not working and does not even exist according to the error in the console. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

```
const sgMail = require(['@@sendgrid/mail']);
                            sgMail.setApiKey('MYAPIKEY');
                            const msg = {
                                to: email_id.value,
                                from: send_email.value,
                                subject: 'Subject',
                                html: '<div>From: ' + send_first_name.value + ' ' + send_last_name.value + '</div><div>Email: ' + send_email.value + '</div><div>Message: ' + message + '</div>',
                            };
                            sgMail.send(msg).then((sent) => {
                                console.log('email sent');
                            })
```

And here are two of the error messages - Mismatched anonymous define() module and TypeError: sgMail.setApiKey is not a function

Comment: Try `const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');`

Comment: I can't because it's a CSHTML page. Anything right after @ is treated as a C# Razor variable

Comment: Ok, but you should still remove the square braces. Also, the code you have won't run in a browser; it's a node script; why is Razor processing it in the first place?